# For loop not calculating value for each df row

Tags: r, for-loop

I am trying to perform a calculation using the formula elo.prob for each I (row) in a data frame. Instead of calculating the value of elo.prob for each row and placing it into a new column, the code keeps calculating elo.prob for the entire data frame and placing the same value in each cell.

My Code:

```
for (i in seq_len(nrow(NHLSince2010))) {
  match = NHLSince2010[i, ]
 
  Hometeam_elo = subset(NHLteams, team == match$Home)$elo
  Awayteam_elo = subset(NHLteams, team == match$Visitor)$elo
  NHLSince2010$eloProbHomeTeamWins <- elo.prob(Hometeam_elo, Awayteam_elo)
}
```

The code produces this result:

[df result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bb3ZI.png)

As you can see the new eloProjectedWinner column just places a value of 0.636 for each row. Instead, I want a different value for each row based upon which team is 'Home' and 'Visitor' in the data frame. Help, please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may need the assignment also indexed or else it gets updated for the whole column and the value we are getting is from the last call of `elo.prob`

```
for (i in seq_len(nrow(NHLSince2010))) {
  match = NHLSince2010[i, ]
 
  Hometeam_elo = subset(NHLteams, team == match$Home)$elo
  Awayteam_elo = subset(NHLteams, team == match$Visitor)$elo
 NHLSince2010$eloProbHomeTeamWins[i] <- elo.prob(Hometeam_elo, Awayteam_elo)
}
```